# Multilayer Exr Color Space from File Output can't be overriden

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management

When I render a multilayer exr from the compositor's *file output* node, the *Color Space* setting has no effect. Why?

[image: multilayer]

> In all other situations the [image] *Color Space* setting works as expected:
>
> - Properties Panel > OpenEXR
> - Properties Panel > OpenEXR Multilayer
> - Compositor File Ouput > OpenEXR